# If the length of a curve equals to the interval, than the derivative is $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, curves

> Let  $X(s)$ be a curve for $0 \le s \le L$, where $L_{[0,s_0]}(X) = s_0$ for every $0 \le s_0 \le L$.
>
> Prove that if $X\in C^1([0,1])$ then $|X'(s)| = 1$ for every  $0 \le s \le L$.

Any **hints**  on that?

I know the formula - $L_{[0,s_0]}(X) =\int^{s_0}_0|X'(s)|ds$ and yet I'm not sure where to start... any ideas?

Comment: This is called _parametrization by arc length_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$ \int_0^{s_0} |X'(s)|\,ds = s_0. $$
Now apply $\frac{d}{ds_0}$ to both sides and use the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: What do you mean "apply $\frac{d}{ds_0}$ to both sides"? What is the result of that? From the Fundamental theorem of calculus I know that we get: $|X(s_0)| - |X(0)| = s_0$. **EDIT** did you mean to apply the $\frac{d}{ds_0}$  after the use of the theorem? From $|X(s_0)| - |X(0)| = s_0$, if I apply it know(If I understand it correctly) I will get $|X'(s_0)| - 0 = 1$?

Comment: I mean differentiate with respect to $s_0$. That is most certainly not what you get after applying the FTC. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part).

Comment: Is it still wrong, after my edit?

Comment: @ChikChak Yes. FTC says that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t) \,dt = f(x)$. In your case $f(x) = |X'(x)|$.

Comment: Ah, I can see it now. What I was looking at was the Newton-Leibniz axiom. Did I at least apply that axiom correctly?

Comment: @ChikChak That is not an axiom, it's a formula. And no - the derivative of $|X(s)|$ is not $|X'(s)|$ because of the absolute value.